# Understanding matrix obtained from indexing with arrays

Tags: python, numpy

In code listed in [logistic regression code](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cs231nfiles/minimal_net.html), I saw the following code snippet.  What throws me off is the expression:
`probs[range(num_examples),y]`. 
Can someone tell me what dimension this matrix has? My guess is that it's a `N*K` by `N*K` matrix, but I am not sure.  Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
N = 100 # number of points per class
D = 2 # dimensionality
K = 3 # number of classes
X = np.zeros((N*K,D))
y = np.zeros(N*K, dtype='uint8')
for j in xrange(K):
  ix = range(N*j,N*(j+1))
  r = np.linspace(0.0,1,N) # radius
  t = np.linspace(j*4,(j+1)*4,N) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # theta
  X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]
  y[ix] = j

#Train a Linear Classifier

# initialize parameters randomly
W = 0.01 * np.random.randn(D,K)
b = np.zeros((1,K))

# some hyperparameters
step_size = 1e-0
reg = 1e-3 # regularization strength

# gradient descent loop
num_examples = X.shape[0]
for i in xrange(200):

  # evaluate class scores, [N x K]
  scores = np.dot(X, W) + b 

  # compute the class probabilities
  exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
  probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True) # [N x K]

  # compute the loss: average cross-entropy loss and regularization
  corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(num_examples),y])
  data_loss = np.sum(corect_logprobs)/num_examples
  reg_loss = 0.5*reg*np.sum(W*W)
  loss = data_loss + reg_loss
  if i % 10 == 0:
```

Comment: I added the missing code from [cs231nfiles notebook](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cs231nfiles/minimal_net.html). Edit out anything unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`probs[range(num_examples), y]` seems to be a 1D slice, where:

- `range(num_examples)` is a vector spanning the length of your samples
- y is a 1D vector, length N*K

Comment: Thanks @smci for the answer and the editing.  I know `np.log` simply does a element log function.  I am more confused on `probs[range(num_examples), y]`,  given that `y` is a `N*K` array,  I wonder what the dimensions are for matrix `probs[range(num_examples), y]`.

Comment: I have no problem with understanding `np.log()` function there.  The problem I have is on `probs[range(num_examples), y]`. What dimension does this matrix have?

Comment: In our case, `np.log()` function only has one parameter `probs[range(num_examples), y]`. Perhaps you think `y` is a parameter of `np.log()`?

Comment: Sorry my brain's tired, yes both those args are 1D arrays inside the `[...]` indexing. `range(num_examples)` is 1D and y is 1D. Edited my answer.